# Send attachment via mail in PHP

Tags: php, export-to-csv, email-attachments

```
if(isset($input->csvrequest)){

  $mailsubject= $input->mailsubject;
  $mailbody= $input->mailbody;
  $mailto= $input->mailto;
  $to = $mailto; 
  $mail_subject = $mailsubject;
  $mail_message = $mailbody;

  $headers = "From: Test <support@test.com>\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: support@test.com\r\n";
  $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "X-Priority: 0\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=win-1251\r\n";

  wp_mail($to, $mail_subject, $mail_message, $headers);

  add_filter('wp_mail_content_type', create_function('', 'return "text/html"; '));
  $arr["error"] = "Email Sent";

}
```

So, this code is sending mail for me. Actually I want to send an attachment with this mail to the user.(For eg: file.csv)

Comment: Hi @Vivek, your question is too hard to be reproduced and it looks like you have poor description of your environment as well. Please check how you can ask good questions.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have uploaded the 'file.csv' in wordpress media library.
Now, setting attachment variable and passing to wp mail function and that's it.
Attachment has started to be sent.

```
    $mail_attachment = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/2021/03/file.csv');
    wp_mail($to, $mail_subject, $mail_message, $headers, $mail_attachment);
```